# How to obtain the current base URL dynamically?

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to make a link within my my webproject that shows the link's url in the link text.

For example, if I'm working on my localhost's Example project, I want a link to the example.jsp page to look like `http://localhost:8081/Example/example.jsp`

Where that will link to the `/example.jsp` page.

I need to be able to do this dynamically.

Comment: Then just do that? What exactly is your question? How to dynamically obtain the hostname, port and/or context name or something?

Comment: Yeah, I need to be able to do this dynamically. I've edited my question

Comment: For when the project is loaded to a server, so it will be able to get the correct full URL for /example.jsp.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) as follows to obtain the site's base URL:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="req" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<c:set var="url">${req.requestURL}</c:set>
<c:set var="base" value="${fn:substring(url, 0, fn:length(url) - fn:length(req.requestURI))}${req.contextPath}/" />
...
```

*(the `req` is in the above example just a shorthand to the current instance of [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), the `<c:set var="url">` line basically converts the `StringBuffer` returned by `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()` to `String` so that it can be used in the string functions)*

Then you can create the link as follows:

```
<a href="${base}example.jsp">${base}example.jsp</a>
```

Or maybe, when using the HTML `<base>` tag which makes all relative links in the document relative to it:

```
<head>
    <base href="${base}" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="example.jsp">${base}example.jsp</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without installing JSTL?

Comment: Yes, just prepare the information in a preprocessing controller servlet (if you have any one... I have the impression that you haven't any one given the fact that you aren't using JSTL), or use *scriptlets* instead (raw Java code embedded in JSPs). *Scriptlets* are however strongly discouraged since over a decade. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I haven't seen that kind of rare code for a while. Your base URL is indeed WORKING. Thanks again!